# Removing variable parts of an output

Tags: python, string

I am working with a pyowm, and I have the following output for requesting the weather of a specific place:

```
<pyowm.webapi25.weather.Weather - reference time=2017-05-22 19:53:00+00, status=Clear>
```

I am trying to get it so that I have a string with **only** the text that follows the status ("Clear", in this case). I haven't really found a way to do this as simply using the replace command wouldn't work since the reference time would change, meaning I can't just say:

`weather = str(weather).replace("pyowm.webapi25.weather.Weather - reference time=2017-05-22 19:53:00+00, status=", "")`

Comment: *a string with only the text that follows the status* - and where is that string?

Comment: I'm assuming this is a print of "Weather" class object which is printed on the shell. You can try doing "weather_obj.get_status()" to get the status string. Here "weather_obj" is the above weather object. Reference: http://pyowm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyowm.webapi25.html#pyowm.webapi25.weather.Weather.get_status

Comment: @PEIN I think you should post as an answer.

Comment: @roganjosh Ok, will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that this is a print of `Weather` class object which is printed on the shell. You can try doing `weather_obj.get_status()` to get the status string from that object. Here `weather_obj` is the above weather object that you have mentioned on the question. 
[Source Implementation Reference.](http://pyowm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pyowm/webapi25/weather.html)
[Doc Reference.](http://pyowm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyowm.webapi25.html#pyowm.webapi25.weather.Weather.get_status)

Comment: @ZnIA You are welcome. You can also accept my answer if the problem is solved.